# TfidfVectorizer stop_words parameter does not work?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a simple piece of code which I'm trying to use as a base for training a model. I was attempting at removing a list of stop words from the vectorizer, but it seems that it does not work.

Or maybe it's me and I'm not passing it the right thing.

Below is my code and you can directly copy-paste and run it if you have sklearn installed.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

l_stop_words = ['is', 'me', 'i']
print type(l_stop_words)

tfvect = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern='[a-zA-Z.0-9+#-/]+[^.]', stop_words=l_stop_words)
tfvect2 = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', token_pattern='[a-zA-Z.0-9+#-/]+[^.]')

corpus = [
     'I know SQL and Java.',
     'I like C# and NoSQL. SQL is fun also.',
     'Teach me ASP.NET and Javascript.',
     'C++ sounds cool and PL/SQL is amazing.']

X = tfvect.fit_transform(corpus)
Y = ['java developer', 'C# developer', 'web developer', 'C++ developer']

X2 = tfvect2.fit_transform(corpus)

print len(tfvect.get_feature_names()), tfvect.get_feature_names()
print len(tfvect2.get_feature_names()), tfvect2.get_feature_names()
```

You will see that when both feature vectors are the same (below is my output).

```
<type 'list'>
20 [u'also', u'amazing', u'and ', u'asp.net ', u'c# ', u'c++ ', u'cool ', u'fun ', u'i ', u'is ', u'java', u'javascript', u'know ', u'like ', u'me ', u'nosql. ', u'pl/sql ', u'sounds ', u'sql ', u'teach ']
20 [u'also', u'amazing', u'and ', u'asp.net ', u'c# ', u'c++ ', u'cool ', u'fun ', u'i ', u'is ', u'java', u'javascript', u'know ', u'like ', u'me ', u'nosql. ', u'pl/sql ', u'sounds ', u'sql ', u'teach ']
```

Any help in finding a solution to this is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that your output features have a whitespace after each word except for the last word of every sentence.

It can be fixed by changing regular expression to

```
'[a-zA-Z.0-9+#-/]*[^.\s]'
```

Then the output would be

```
17 ['also', 'amazing', 'and', 'asp.net', 'c#', 'c++', 'cool', 'fun', 'java', 'javascript', 'know', 'like', 'nosql', 'pl/sql', 'sounds', 'sql', 'teach']
20 ['also', 'amazing', 'and', 'asp.net', 'c#', 'c++', 'cool', 'fun', 'i', 'is', 'java', 'javascript', 'know', 'like', 'me', 'nosql', 'pl/sql', 'sounds', 'sql', 'teach']
```

**Edit #1**

The above regex might match a single character that is not in the character set `[a-zA-Z.0-9+#-/]`, for example `!`.

```
'[a-zA-Z0-9#-/]*[a-zA-Z0-9#--/]'
```

may better meet the purpose of the original regex.

(The `.` and `+` in `[a-zA-Z.0-9+#-/]` can be omitted as they are within the range of `#-/`)

**Edit #2**

Thanks to the comments, I realized that I misunderstood your purpose. Actually you only want to match `.`, `+`, `#`, `-`, `/`, but `#-\` would be a range. So you need to use backslash to escape the `-`.

```
'[a-zA-Z.0-9+#\-/]*[a-zA-Z0-9+#\-/]'
```

Comment: Didn't notice that on my features. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I support this answer and propose a shorter regular expression `token_pattern=r'[^.\s]+'`

Comment: @lanenok but this would separate words like `asp.net`

Comment: Wow, thanks for the edit on this. So far the original regex worked, but I will try this second option. Also, didn't know that `# - /` would be considered a range. I thought that I was actually enumerating the characters I wanted to be included in the regex. This is great info!

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu if you didn't know `#-/` would be a range, I think your actual intention is to match only `.`, `+`, `#`, `-`, `/`, right?

Comment: @yangjie Yes, exactly. I think I can actually classify this as a fortunate mistake.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu that would be a mistake, since the range also contains some other characters. I edited my answer again, cheers.